# Upload image via jquery/ajax with only the image path

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

Am  working on a Phonegap application . One portion of it requires text and image file to be uploaded via Ajax.

have tested the Ajax file upload independently and it seems to work when used with input type = file . but can we upload a file by using only its path on the machine.

The idea is actually to use the Phonegap API to let user Take / select an image from the device and return its FILE URI .

```
 so can we use the file URI  to upload the file via ajax.
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap has a FileTransfer API that lets you upload a file to a server with only its file name.

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Full docs here... http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: thank you for the answer ..can we send text/file combination. there is actually a form with about 7-8 textfields and an image.

Comment: Yes, you can pass in additional form parameters in the options when you call `upload`... http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions

Comment: thank you... have marked as valid answer as it seems to provide the required data. However have ended up using the HTML 5  file API and file input tag.

Answer (score 0):

have selected the answer as it seems to provide the required information. However for the sake of information, have ended up using the HTML 5 file API . the code is as follows:

```
                <label for="imagefile">
                    <img src="../../images/businessapp/no-image.png" title="choose image" id="buisnessimage" />
                </label>
                <input type="file" id="imagefile" style="display:none;" />
```

the javascript/jquery is as under:

```
$("#imagefile").change(function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var file = $("#imagefile").prop('files')[0];

    reader.onload = function(e){
        var dataurl  = reader.result;
        $("#buisnessimage").prop('src', dataurl);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

for uploading, the `FormData` has been used as below:

```
var form = new FormData();

form.append('name', $("#BusinessName").val());
form.append('Email', $("#Email").val());
form.append('address', $("#Address").val());
form.append('phone', $("#BusinessPhone").val());
form.append('city', $("#City").val());
form.append('state', $("#State").val());
form.append('website', $("#Website").val());
form.append('logo', $("#imagefile").prop('files')[0]);
```

AJAX options are as follows:

```
url: <url>;
    type: "POST",
    data: form,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
```

hope it helps someone :)